The meaning of "Super Size Me"
I was checking the "Super Size Me" documentary.
I would like to know the meaning of the term "Super size me". Which scenario has the right meaning?

"Super size" as a verb: make me super size or make me big

"Super size" as an adjective: Me that has the characteristic of
being super size: the big me



Make my burger meal bigger (make it super size).

It's explained in the film and in the film's Wikipedia page.

You've got a correct explanation for the expression in its proper context - when ordering a meal in McDonalds. But to answer your question more directly - yes, I think there probably is a duality of meaning in the title of the documentary movie. The "me" in "Supersize Me" really means "my order" when ordering food, but as the documentary is about the effects on the subject's health (and in particular, their size and weight) from eating McDonald's food exclusively, the "me" in the title could refer to the subject. He is being 'supersized'.
I can't find any sources that specifically state that as a fact in the case of Supersize Me but it's pretty common in movie titles. Some examples that are attested to include "Face Off" (which means a confrontation, but in the context of the movie the characters literally remove their faces) and "Adaptation" (the movie refers both to how plants 'adapt' but also to how books are 'adapted' into movies).

He is being 'supersized' yes, exactly. And his liver ruined.

Supersize began as an ad-agency invention, a trademarked description of a size of a serving in McDonald’s restaurants. So Supersize me soon became colloquial for an order meaning essentially “I’d like a drink or serving of fries that is super-sized.” So it’s essentially, “Serve me an extremely large quantity!”
(As discussed in a report from NBC news, the chain announced in 2004 that it would discontinue their Supersize items, ostensibly to increase the healthfulness of their offerings.)
The phrase’s emphatic tone, brevity, and alliteration have all contributed to its entering contemporary slang.

It was specifically a McDonalds campaign to upsell customers on larger portions of products they were ordering, and not, to my knowledge, ever generally used in other fast-food restaurants. They dropped it in 2004.

Thanks, @Spehro'speff'Pefhany, for the lead. I have Googled a bit and enhanced my answer to incorporate the further details.
